# git clone failing, can't repack on remote

Tags: git, dvcs, corruption

While researching this I have found a **lot** of messages about this concerning the exhaustion of memory, but I am not actually getting any malloc errors.

When I try and clone I get this mid-compression

```
error: git-upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git-upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

When I go to the remote and run `git gc` it gives me this.. (same amount through compression)

```
error: failed to run repack
```

When I run `git fsck` I get no output at all...

ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git checking out problem \[fatal: early EOFs\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505644/git-checking-out-problem-fatal-early-eofs)

Comment: @Amber how would this have anything to do with the network protocal? My commands running **on the remote** are failing...

Comment: There's more than one answer listed in the linked question.

Comment: @Amber and none are marked correct...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the line you should see *before*  `git-pack-objects died with error`.

For instance, if you should see a line like:

```
remote: fatal: object 21f3981dd35fccd28febabd96f27241eea856c50 is corrupted
```

(as described in "[GIT pull error - remote object is corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170317/git-pull-error-remote-object-is-corrupted)")

In that case, you might try (on the remote server) a `git fsck --full 21f3981 ; git repack` (as suggested by [J-16 SDiZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88442/j-16-sdiz))

You will find similar error message in this [old (2008) thread](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/7/31/253475), with [Linus Torvald suggesting](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/7/31/253494), for an error message like "`unable to unpack .. header`":

The "`unable to unpack .. header`" problem would at a guess be a totally 
corrupted loose object. You should have a file named

```
.git/objects/b2/8b949a1a3c8eb37ca6eefd024508fa8b253429
```

> and it sounds like that file is corrupt.
>   So far, apart from a CRLF conversion bug (that you wouldn't have triggered on OS X anyway), I think every single time we've seen that, it's been a real disk or memory 
>   corruption.

Comment: before that line it gets 62% through the compression,  same percentage when I run `git gc` on the remote.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: so, no other error message at any line *before* the "died with error" message?

Comment: right, it gets about 62% through compression, stops, then outputs the above message. Also, as the question points out when I run `git fsck` i get no output, indicated that git has no knowledge of corrupted files or problems. correct?

Comment: @jondavidjohn: yes, correct. Just to be extra-sure, you did run the `fsck` on the remote server? Can you try on the remote a `git fsck --full`?

Comment: sure, yes that was on the remote server, I'll try the --full option.