# Can't git clone from github. remote: fatal: failed to apply delta

Tags: git, github, repository, clone, delta

Since a few days, one of my GitHub repository seems to be corrupted.
When trying to clone the repository with the following command line :

```
git clone git@github.com:MyAccount/MyRepository.git
```

I get the following output :

```
Cloning into 'MyRepository'...
remote: fatal: failed to apply delta
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Moreover, when some people of my team can still pull the repository, while some people can't getting this error:

```
git pull
remote: fatal: failed to apply delta
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

Does anyone know what could have happened and/or how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub is currently facing issues with ssh access (see [GitHub status history](https://status.github.com/messages))

> We are currently investigating SSH access problems on one of our fileserver pairs. A small number of repositories may be affected.

So first check if the cloning problem persists with an https url:

```
git clone  https://github.com/MyAccount/MyRepository
```

If the problem persists, then you need to contact GitHub support, asking them for a `git fsck`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4170317/6309).

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still occurs :  
git clone  https://github.com/MyAccount/MyRepository  
Cloning into 'MyRepository'...  
remote: fatal: failed to apply delta  
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.  
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header

Comment: @Drico ok, I have edited the answer: seems that GitHub support needs to have a look at your repo then.

Comment: After a few time, github succeedeed in solving this issue. Thanks !

Comment: @Drico Excellent! Did GitHub provided a detailed explanation of the issue regarding your repo?

Comment: not yet, they say are still investigating the root cause of the corruption, but they restored a copy of the corrupted object from their backups.