# Git: object is corrupted while cloning

Tags: git, clone, gitolite

I just created a new repo with Gitolite, and another user can successfully clone, commit, push and pull from that.

The repo is brand new and contains one file only. Oddly enough, I can't clone it on my own machine. All I get is what follows:

```
$ git clone ssh://gitolite@remoteserver/myrepo.git
Cloning into 'myrepo'...

###########
(SSH welcome message here)
###########

fatal: object 44df53e172de1448b139674fefb6ced3b1ddbfcb is corrupted
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can an object be corrupted in a brand new repo?!? Besides, I'm working with several other repos that I cloned from the very same remote machine, never had a problem like this.

Of course I *can* start over, create a new repo, copy the file there and go on, but I'd like to understand why this happens.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of Git was in use?  Are the permissions correct?

Comment: git version 1.9.0.msysgit.0 -- permissions are correct for sure

Comment: Hrmph.  I see you're using Gitolite as well, which is a fantastic backend.  You didn't happen to keep a copy of the repository around, did you?  Myself or someone on the Git dev list might be able to do a post-mortem and figure what's wrong.  Or at least, what kind of corruption there is which could lead to what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have to answer my own question after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170317/git-pull-error-remote-object-is-corrupted).

I already had performed a `git fsck` On the remote repo (`myrepo.git` directory), no luck. Then I performed a

```
git fsck --full 44df53e172de1448b139674fefb6ced3b1ddbfcb
git repack
```

and everything worked again.

Question should stay open, actually, because I can't figure out yet **why** on earth this could happen.

:-)