# git clone error:remote: error: Out of memory

Tags: git

```
remote: Counting objects: 67741, done.
remote: error: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 343989657 bytes)
remote: error: failed to read object 0a52bbb6aecced35f3ebcce0d840d1c5b92ff636 at offset 39490917 from ./objects/pack/pack-b47659f213738c8a7290f6e68cfb1900a6640333.pack
remote: fatal: packed object 0a52bbb6aecced35f3ebcce0d840d1c5b92ff636 (stored in ./objects/pack/pack-b47659f213738c8a7290f6e68cfb1900a6640333.pack) is corrupt
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

Comment: git server used gogs

Comment: if you have too much application opened,this error may occur

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT pull error - remote object is corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170317/git-pull-error-remote-object-is-corrupted)

Comment: should I increase server memory？